# React useEffect is not triggering on redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

i have a function called login that redirects the user to the main page if everything was ok. Then, on the main page, i want to fetch some user info with useEffect using the token the was stored when the user logged in, but nothing happens. Only when i refresh the page i get the data.

**login function**

```
export const login = ({ email, password, history }) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("userToken", data.user);
        history.push("/");
      } else {
        dispatch(
          setNotification({
            variant: "error",
            message: data.message,
          })
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };
};
```

**fetch user funtion**

```
export const fetchUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/userInfo", {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("userToken"),
        },
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      dispatch(setUser({
        id: data.id,
        fullname: data.fullname,
        email: data.email
      }))
    } catch (error) {}
  };
};
```

**useEffect on my main page**

```
useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(fetchUser()); 
  }, []);
```

**backend function**

```
module.exports.getCurrentUser = async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
  try {
    const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, "123");
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: verifyToken.email });
    return res.json({
      id: user._id,
      fullname: user.fullname,
      email: user.email
    })
  
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

Comment: what is the point of your `isMounted`?  You set it to true every time before you test the value

Comment: i´m using it to work around an error i was getting.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter to `useEffect` tells it when it needs to run. It only runs if one of the values in the array has changed. Since you pass an empty array, none of the values in it have changed.

This is presuming your app probably starts at '/', then detects there is no user so switches to the login screen. When it goes back to the root, it only executes `useEffect` if something in the array has changed from the previous render.

As it is, the `isMounted` doesn't make much sense. This could simply be:

```
useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(fetchUser());
  });
```

Comment: not working yet :(

Comment: you just edited question and still has the `[]` at the end. The `[]` parameter is your problem.

Comment: it does not work even if i remove the [ ]

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `setUser`, but what is calling your login function?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).